# How can i add a column to a dataframe based on a conditional of another dataframe that has a different length, but shared column data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes of different lengths and different columns, but a shared column with the same identifying data.  They look like this

observations DF:

| index | scientific_name | park_name | observations |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | name1 | park1 | 10 |
| 1 | name2 | park2 | 12 |

species DF:

| index | scientific_name | common_names | category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | name1 | name1,name2 | Mammal |
| 1 | name2 | name1,name2 | Vascular plant |

I am trying to create a new column in the observatiosn DF called 'category' that is filled with data based on the shared scientific_names between both tables.  I've tried using pd.merge but it doesn't fill the category column the way I want.  Concat does not either.  When i tried using a list comprehension it gave me a value error too.  Any thoughts?

I tried using a list comprehension like so:

```
observations['category'] = [el for el in species['category'] if observations['scientific_name'] == species['scientific_name]]
```

This results in an error.

Comment: can you provide the desired output and the result of using `pd.merge`?

Comment: |index | scientific_name } | park_name | observations | category|
| ------ | ------| ------ | --------
0 | name1 | park1 | 10 | Mammal
1 | name2 | park2 | 12 | Vascular Plant

Each row's 'category' is filled based on the respective condition of observations['scientific_name'] == species['scientific_name'].  So if the scientific names match, the row on in observations DF gets filled with the respective category that is in the species DF.  With no NaN's given or additional rows added to the DF

Comment: **spec_obs_df = observations.merge(
    species,
    how='left',
    left_on='scientific_name',
    right_on='scientific_name'
)**  This returns a dataframe with additional rows which is not what i want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only wanted to add the "category" column from `species` to `observations` based on the shared column "scientific_name", this should work.

```
observations = pd.merge(observations, species[['scientific_name', 'category']])
```

Comment: This adds additional rows to the dataframe though.  i want to maintain the same length of the original dataframe, just merely with the additional information of 'category' for each record in the dataframe.

Comment: that would suggest that there are duplicate "scientific_name" values in `species`

Comment: I did a conditional verification to see if they are unique and they are.  This is how I did it:

obs_sci_name = observations['scientific_name'].value_counts().sort_index()
spec_sci_name = species['scientific_name'].value_counts().sort_index()
print(observations['scientific_name'].value_counts().sort_index(), species['scientific_name'].value_counts().sort_index())
if obs_sci_name.index.equals(spec_sci_name.index):
    print('they are identical')
else:
    print('they are not equal')

It returned they are identical

Comment: There were duplicate values in the species dataframe.  i am curious to why observations.drop_duplicates() removed duplicates but species.drop_duplicates() did not.  Thank you!